# Getting Null in User Object

Tags: java, facebook, oop, facebook-graph-api

Hi there I am writing a program in which I am getting information from my Facebook account but every time when I print something I always get Null. Anyone who can help? 
Thanks in Advance :)
Here is my Code

```
import com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient;
import com.restfb.FacebookClient;
import com.restfb.types.User;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String facebookAccessTokes = "<token>";
        @Deprecated
        FacebookClient fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(facebookAccessTokes);
        User me = fbClient.fetchObject("me",User.class);
        System.out.println(me.getLink());

    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried doing "<EAACEdEose0cBAENlR46W2C9KYzrI7PkziZC6gACCrHhMTbZB7juFqaQwHoc7kDeKaifJiN2IwSXCBzmMNEyjFTKtvyicIAGVaYUc9xkaMtoTgbRqyiUlIIUrgiDu5wZC5iH7TD1fo2KcOA11eutFWZCXERnPVI1gZCbvnXBN3cw6vtMI9L1kfaENZA2IsMnJxB925uby9bQwZDZD>" but there came an exception naming Invalid OAuth access token.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be posting your Facebook client access token.  I was trying to be helpful there, but since you insist...

Comment: This is proper access token generated by Graph Api Explorer

Comment: "This is proper access token generated by Graph Api Explorer" - I think you are missing the point.

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)? If you do server to server calls, use `AccessToken accessToken =
  new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainAppAccessToken(MY_APP_ID, MY_APP_SECRET);`